# IronPython - No module named "cx_Oracle"

Tags: ironpython, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to the Oracle DB with IronPython using VS2015, but I get the following error:

> Additional information: No module named cx_Oracle

But：

1. cx_Oracle works good in python
2. I already installed the cx_Oracle

[C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDM4p.png)

Who can help me to solve this case? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please include relevant code in your question so that we may help you.